# What is a hardware bit?

Tags: operating-systems

I am taking an OS course. While going through the user and kernel space, I come across the mode bit. The book (Silberschatz, Galvin, and Gagne)says that it is a hardware bit. What is a hardware bit?

Comment: I guess it means its semantics are known to hardware. Unlike, say, application memory, where only the application knows what’s what.

Comment: Answered in [operating system - Where is the mode bit? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185300/where-is-the-mode-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hardware bit is a two-state (i.e. True/False or 0/1) configuration value that directly changes the behaviour of the hardware. In other words it is "hard-wired" to configure the behaviour of the hardware.

In some cases hardware bits can be accessed directly by software; in other cases they cannot. For example, on most processors there are instructions to test or modify the carry flag, which is another example of a hardware bit. However, the "mode bit" cannot be changed directly (especially from user mode!).